# Get object's DataContext

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0, datacontext

If I have the LINQ objects:

```
public class SampleDataContext : DataContext {
    public Table<Customer> Customers { get { return this.GetTable<Customer>(); } }
    public SampleDataContext( string connectionString ) : base( connectionString ) { }
}

[Table( Name="dbo.tblCustomers" )]
public class Customer {
    private Guid? customerID;
    [Column( Storage="customerID", DbType="uniqueidentifier NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true )]
    public Guid? CustomerID {
        get { return this.customerID; }
        set { this.customerID = value; }
    }

    private string customerName;
    [Column( Storage = "customerName", DbType = "nvarchar(255) NOT NULL" )]
    public string CustomerName {
        get { return this.customerName; }
        set { this.customerName = value; }
    }
}
```

and somewhere else in application:

```
public static void DoSomethingWithCustomer( Customer customer ) {
    // some operations
    // now, I want save changes to the database
}
```

how can I get instance of DataContext which tracks changes of the "customer" object?

**Edit: Why I don't want pass the DataContext into method.**

1) Passing always 2 objects instead of 1 is "ugly" pattern for whole application.

- Methods will need next parameter for every business object.
- Collection will needs changed from "List" to "List>".

Both points will more hard to maintain - developer must every-time sets the correct instance of DataContext (easy to create a bug), despite the DataContext know that the concrete object is(or not) attached to another DataContext.

2) I want (current version of application use it) process "any" business logic on collection of objects which came from different "places" ( floating windows by drag & drop for example ).

Currentyl we use custom typed DataSets, so informations about changes are in the data rows (DataRow = business object) and wasn't problem to get it, or create a clone and then save it into database.

Comment: Re your comment to me, you simply shouldn't use that approach: that implies that the data-context is *also*  long-lived (since the two are linked implicitly), but data-contexts should generally be considered short-lived resources.

Comment: I revised our requirements and linq capbilities, and it looks the linq-to-sql is not the right way, we should go. Maybe the linq-to-entities can provide required functionality.

Thanks both for answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kevin - I feel your pain... when you are building business logic around your business objects, there are times when you simply *have* to have access to the DataContext to which an object belongs, since not knowing the DataContext menas having to put your code in places that reduce the maintainability of your code.

I wrote the following code (VB, I'm afraid), which presents a Context property which can be placed onto a data object, and then used to return the DataContext (if any) that the object is attached to.

```
Private Const StandardChangeTrackerName As String = "System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker+StandardChangeTracker"

Private _context As DataClasses1DataContext
Public Property Context() As DataClasses1DataContext
    Get
        Dim hasContext As Boolean = False
        Dim myType As Type = Me.GetType()
        Dim propertyChangingField As FieldInfo = myType.GetField("PropertyChangingEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        Dim propertyChangingDelegate As PropertyChangingEventHandler = propertyChangingField.GetValue(Me)
        Dim delegateType As Type = Nothing

        For Each thisDelegate In propertyChangingDelegate.GetInvocationList()
            delegateType = thisDelegate.Target.GetType()
            If delegateType.FullName.Equals(StandardChangeTrackerName) Then
                propertyChangingDelegate = thisDelegate
                hasContext = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If hasContext Then
            Dim targetField = propertyChangingDelegate.Target
            Dim servicesField As FieldInfo = targetField.GetType().GetField("services", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
            If servicesField IsNot Nothing Then

                Dim servicesObject = servicesField.GetValue(targetField)

                Dim contextField As FieldInfo = servicesObject.GetType.GetField("context", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)

                _context = contextField.GetValue(servicesObject)

            End If
        End If
    
        Return _context
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataClasses1DataContext)

        _context = value

    End Set

End Property
```

Here is a C# version:

```
public DataContext GetMyDataContext()
{
    // Find the StandardChangeTracker listening to property changes on this object.
    // If no StandardChangeTracker is listening, then this object is probably not
    // attached to a data context.
    var eventField = this.GetType().GetField("PropertyChangingEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var eventDelegate = eventField.GetValue(this) as Delegate;
    if (eventDelegate == null)
        return null;
    eventDelegate = eventDelegate.GetInvocationList().FirstOrDefault(
        del => del.Target.GetType().FullName == "System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker+StandardChangeTracker");
    if (eventDelegate == null)
        return null;

    // Dig through the objects to get the underlying DataContext.
    // If the following fails, then there was most likely an internal change
    // to the LINQ-to-SQL framework classes.
    var targetField = eventDelegate.Target;
    var servicesField = targetField.GetType().GetField("services", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var servicesObject = servicesField.GetValue(targetField);
    var contextField = servicesObject.GetType().GetField("context", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    return (DataContext)contextField.GetValue(servicesObject);
}
```

Take care to note that the object can only locate it's DataContext if it is currently attached to the context with ChangeTracking switched on. This property relies on the fact that the DataContext has subscribed to the object's OnPropertyChanging event to monitor changes over the lifespan of the object.

If this was helpful, please up-vote this post.

For more info on using reflection to find event handlers:

- [http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2007/03/29/reflecting-over-an-event.aspx](https://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/reflecting-over-an-event)
- https://web.archive.org/web/20131213074318/http://bobpowell.net/eventsubscribers.aspx

Comment: +1 This way is littlebit "hacky", but propably do, what I searched.
Now, I'm using LINQ IQuerableToolkit ( from CodePlex ), and I'm totaly happy :).

Comment: I added a C# version of the method, with a couple minor changes: 1) It's a method instead of a property, and 2) It intentionally fails instead of returning null if a change to the framework internals broke the method.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the fun of [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) is that you can't be sure that the object *knows* who is tracking him. If the object has data-aware / lazy-loading properties, then you *might* be able to trace the context via reflection, but in reality this would be a mess. It would be far cleaner to simply pass the data-context to the code that needs it.

Comment: I want to use my object in "whole" application. Passing DataContext for every instance of business object is not practical :/.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is to pass the DataContext into your method.

However, you may also consider changing your design so that you follow the rule that "a single method should have only one purpose", in which case you wouldn't want to "Save" in the same method that you "Modify".